# Linting error `import` can only be used in `import()` or `import.meta`. (1:1)

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, lint, prettier, prettier-eslint

This project was written by someone else, and I need to work on it from hereon. I thought that the first step should be to fix the formatting. Normally, I just use .prettierrc in my vscode, and a run a alt-shift-f, or ctrl-s to format the code in each file. I tried to use eslint, but got all kinds of errors, so I got rid of it (uninstalled all the eslint dev-dependencies in the project, as was the case before I started working on it). I have the prettier and the eslint extensions installed in vscode.

Error

```
["ERROR" - 1:45:44 pm] Error formatting document.
["ERROR" - 1:45:44 pm] `import` can only be used in `import()` or `import.meta`. (1:1)
> 1 | import { subMonths, isSameDay, format, isYesterday, isToday, subDays, subYears } from 'date-fns';
    | ^
  2 |
  3 | export const today = new Date();
  4 | export const last7Day = {
SyntaxError: `import` can only be used in `import()` or `import.meta`. (1:1)
```

root > .vscode > settings.json

```
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    // other configs
}
```

root > frontend > .prettierrc

```
{
  "arrowParens": "always",
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "endOfLine": "lf",
  "htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "css",
  "insertPragma": false,
  "jsxBracketSameLine": false,
  "jsxSingleQuote": false,
  "printWidth": 80,
  "proseWrap": "preserve",
  "quoteProps": "as-needed",
  "requirePragma": false,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": false,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "useTabs": false,
  "vueIndentScriptAndStyle": false,
  "parser": "json"
}
```

How do I get my prettier file to ignore this error? It's coming on all the files.
OS: Windows 10

UPDATE: This is the following in my package.json.
I don't normally install prettier, but I'm at a bit of a loss at what to do. From my understanding, this was more of a IDE-thing, rather than a project thing.

```
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": ["react-app", "react-app/jest"]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [">0.2%", "not dead", "not op_mini all"],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "^2.5.1"
  }
```

Comment: Running into the same issue. Did you ever solve it?

Comment: Don't remember mate. But I think I managed to get it back then. Have a new problem though. Formatter is only formatting `.tsx` files, but not `.ts` files. No idea how I got here, or how to get out of it.

Comment: Somewhere in the TS config, I think you can define which file extensions to view. That should fix your `.ts` issue.